# Randomize lines of really huge text file

Tags: c#, performance, memory, file-io

I would like to randomize the lines in a file which has over 32 million lines of 10 digit strings. I am aware of how to do it with `File.ReadAllLines(...).OrderBy(s => random.Next()).ToArray()` but this is not memory efficient since it will load everything into memory (over 1.4GB) and works only with x64 architecture.

The alternative would be to split it and randomize the shorter files and then merge them but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Do all lines have the same length? That would make it much easier...

Comment: If you just do the 'ReadAllLines' without the OrderBy, how much memory is used? Is that already too much?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque yes all lines are of the same size.

Comment: @Baldrick yes this happens no matter the OrderBy

Comment: Count amount of lines? And rand(min, max)?

Comment: @JanCzarny I am not sure I follow..

Comment: `.OrderBy(s => random.Next())` is not guaranteed to terminate. The function in the `OrderBy` clause is supposed to provide a total ordering. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/20/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This application demonstrates what you want, using a byte array

1. It creates a file with the padded numbers 0 to 32000000.
2. It loads the file, then shuffles them in memory, using a block-copying Fisher-Yates method.
3. Finally, it writes the file back out in shuffled order

Peak memory usage is about 400 MB. Runs in about 20 seconds on my machine (mostly file IO).

```
public class Program
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create massive file
        var random = new Random();
        const int lineCount = 32000000;

        var file = File.CreateText("BigFile.txt");

        for (var i = 0; i < lineCount ; i++)
        {
            file.WriteLine("{0}",i.ToString("D10"));
        }

        file.Close();

        int sizeOfRecord = 12;

        var loadedLines = File.ReadAllBytes("BigFile.txt");

        ShuffleByteArray(loadedLines, lineCount, sizeOfRecord);

        File.WriteAllBytes("BigFile2.txt", loadedLines);
    }

    private static void ShuffleByteArray(byte[] byteArray, int lineCount, int sizeOfRecord)
    {
        var temp = new byte[sizeOfRecord];

        for (int i = lineCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(0, i + 1);
            // copy i to temp
            Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, sizeOfRecord * i, temp, 0, sizeOfRecord);
            // copy j to i
            Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, sizeOfRecord * j, byteArray, sizeOfRecord * i, sizeOfRecord);
            // copy temp to j
            Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, byteArray, sizeOfRecord * j, sizeOfRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you are right that the peak memory is about 400M the output file is not correct... I get things a file full of things like this
47
30090968697002
3064902714
34101
307516974214
30

Comment: @idipous: Hmmm.. gets perfect output for me. Do you see that issue using my exact sample, or changing it to be used with your file? Bear in mind if your lines are 10 characters long, the size-of-record should be 12. You need 2 extra characters for the line terminator. Might be different if you're running Mono too.

Comment: Note: Just fixed error in temp byte array declaration - had made it far too big (shouldn't affect your output, but worth noting)

Comment: To get the sizeofrecord I did `sizeOfRecord = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(line);` where line comes from reading throught the file and all lines are the same size but different number so I just pick the last.

Comment: If the 'line' you're getting the length of is a string got from 'ReadLines', then it won't include the line terminator. That's not included. You'll probably have to add 2 to that number.

Comment: I had to add 1 to the bytecount. I am worried about this being something that might change (e.g. linux vs windows file) but I am sure I will find a way to read the whole line including any trailing characters

Comment: @idipous: So it's working ok for you now? Excellent.

Comment: @idipous: If you're handling a text file as binary (which is probably the fastest way in this case), you sadly have to work around different platforms' ways of dealing with text files...

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach will allocate at least 2 large string arrays (probably more -- I don't know how OrderBy is implemented, but it probably does its own allocations).

If you randomize the data "in-place" by doing random permutations between the lines (e.g. using the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)), it will minimize the memory usage. Of course it will still be large if the file is large, but you won't allocate more memory than necessary.

---

EDIT: if all lines have the same length (*), it means you can do random access to a given line in the file, so you can do the Fisher-Yates shuffle directly in the file.

(*) and assuming you're not using an encoding where characters can have different byte lengths, like UTF-8

Comment: In order to do the Fisher-Yates shuffle won't I need to load all the lines in memory and then do the in place shuffle? Or can this be done without loading the file in memory

Comment: @idipous, yes, you still need to load all lines in memory. It's not ideal, but it's better to load them 2 or 3 times as you were doing.

Comment: @idipous, yes, sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Yes it's only digits of the same length (e.g. one file can have 32M 10 digit numbers and another file irrelevant though to the first can have 3M 9 digit numbers). I will give it a try and let you know.